# Comparing two datasets of communication flows

Tags: clustering, dataset, multiple-comparisons, similarities

I know the question of how to compare two datasets has been asked multiple times and I have read a lot about the different tests available but I'm a little lost on what exactly the tests show and what I need to do.

I have **two datasets**, both contain TCP communication of a system which gets aggregated into flow statistics, so for every connection there is a **multitude of statistical features** such as average length of packages, time between packages, etc.

Both datasets come from the same simulated system (and additionally different anomalies have been simulated on the systems) **the difference is that one has been TLS encrypted and the other has not** (+ the recordings are from independant runs, so while the stem from the same system simulation, there is no one-to-one association between the two datasets).

My assumption is, that (from the perspective of clustering) the datasets are essentially the same. So e.g. the mean of certain values might shift (because e.g. encryption adds overhead, so packages are going to be larger/slightly more numerous) but I'm hoping to show, that from the perspective of a clustering algorithm, they are "structured the same" or provide the same amount of information/separation.

I would be glad for any help/ideas on methods/tests that would help me prove/disprove this assumption (or at least find indicators), ideally both from the clustering perspective and a more general statistical tests (e.g. I looked into the t-test - which seems to make no sense in this context)